# USB host controller doesn't support USB Hub

Tags: linux, usb

I have a 3rd party USB Host controller (based on SL811) that does not support USB Hub, What would be the best way to implement support and is it at all possible?

Comment: The Linux SL811 driver already has hub support included. But the problem is, the SL811/SL811HS host controllers have a hardware erratum (bug) that makes it impossible for them to work with some hubs that are actually compliant to the USB specifications. Even [the manufacturer's datasheet](www.cypress.com/files/sl811hs-embedded-usb-hostslave-controller-datasheetpdf) does not have a workaround for the bug, other than choosing a hub that won't trigger the bug.

Comment: Do you have a link to a hub that work with sl811?

Comment: Unfortunately not. But from the datasheet, emphasis mine: "The only complete workaround is to use a hub that does not transmit SE0s upstream during EOF1. Some hubs, **including all Cypress hubs**, have the option to disable SE0s from being generated during EOF1. For a list of hubs that do not generate SE0s upstream during EOF1, or for more information on disabling this feature in Cypress hubs, contact Cypress USB support."